# How to teach a High school student that complex numbers cannot be totally ordered?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, education, ordered-fields

I once again need your precious knowledge! I am not sure which is the best pedagogic way to teach a High school student about why complex numbers cannot be totally ordered. When I was in High school we were simply told that we cannot order complex numbers. When we asked why the answer was because there is no total order in $\mathbb C$. But we weren't taught a thing about order in general. Is there a crystal clear way to do this in High school? I am thanking you all in advance!

Comment: You can totally order $\mathbb{C}$. You cannot make it an ordered field, and that's easily seen by the fact that in ordered fields nonzero squares are positive. But $-1 = i^2$ is a square, as is $1 = 1^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into exactly what an ordered field is, you can tell your students that if you want to order $\mathbb{C}$, two things that should be true of the order is

1. The order preserves the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$.
2. For $a,b,c$ with $b<c$, then $ab<ac$ if $a>0$ and $ab>ac$ if $a<0$.

Then ask: Where is $i$ in the ordering compared to $0$?

Comment: Condition 1 can be replaced with $a>b$ implies $a+c>b+c$ and condition 2 with $a>0,b>0$ implies $ab>0$.

Comment: I find it more fun to ask students to compare $i$ and 1, as it then becomes less obvious and they have to do more manipulations, and they all get excited that $i^2 = -1$. Often, after enough time, they come up with comparing $i$ and 0 by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

*Algebraic*. The condition for a field to be orderable is that sums of nonzero squares are nonzero.     The complex numbers are designed to violate that.

*Geometric*. Take a regular $2n$ sided polygon in the complex plane, with center at $0$.  Vertices $2k$ steps apart (moving from vertex to neighboring vertex) differ by a factor $(w^2)^k$ for $w$ a root of unity, which must be positive as a power of a nonzero square, so that all the even numbered vertices have the same sign in any ordering.  But the sum of all the even vertices is zero by symmetry.

*Quadratically closed*.  Every nonzero complex number is a square, which should make it positive, but then $z$ and $-z$ cannot have opposite signs.